# Adding counted rows to running number in UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to `UPDATE` usernames to our database, but I have problem with UQ.

In our schema we have corporate admin users and contacts in the same table. Every corporate has 1 admin user which where composed by taking 6 characters from their name and adding running number (if there were 6 character duplicates).

For example:

CompanyName: **Test Company**
UserName: **testco-1**

Running number with admin users (with the same 6 character start) varies from 1 to 15(ish).

Our contact table has column `CorporateAdminId` which is set to NULL with Admin users, but contacts are referred to admin user with this field. So the table has a relationship to itself.

> NOTE: Before contacts did not have usernames
>   Because software upgrades our contacts need to have username also. Usernames to contacts are created with the same rule (6 char+running number) and the first 6 characters are defined by AdminUserId reference (not the contacts own corporate name)

**For example:**

AdminUserId: **GUID** (Refers to Test Company)
CompanyName: **Data miner**
UserName: **testco-2**

My problem here is that how can I count how many usernames there are in the database at the moment that ***start f.e with 'testco'*** and add this number to the running number that I use to create contact usernames (so there will be no collissions with UQ)

EDIT: Current query used in update

```
SELECT LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(A.CorporateName, ' ','')), 10)+'-
    '+CAST(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY      
    SUBSTRING(A.Username,1,CHARINDEX('0',A.Username)))+(ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY B.AdminUserId ORDER BY
    LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(A.CompanyName, ' ','')),10))) as nvarchar(255)) FROM
    Contact B INNER JOIN Contact A ON a.Id = B.AdminUserId
```

Problem with this is that It adds the number of rows that are going to be updated instead of rows that have username as 'xxxxxx' in db.

Comment: row_number  partition by

Comment: you can count the usernames starting with "testco%' and find the number. However, what happens when you delete users? you can still get duplicate names. Another way is to try from "1" to see which numbers are already there and use the "unused" one.

Comment: edited current query

Answer (score 1):

```
select username, left(username, 6)
     , row_number() (partition by left(username, 6) order by username) rn 
  from table
```